# Issue with custom theme after upgrade from Magento 2.2.9 to Magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento, magento2

I have upgraded my Magento 2 store from 2.2.9 to 2.4.2. There is 2 themes are active.

**Theme One** working for overall site. This theme is working fine. The parent theme for this is **Blank Theme**.

**Theme Two** is for particular category and product associated with that category. There is issue with this theme the layout is not rendering in frontend in product view page. The parent theme for this is **Theme One**.

Any one can help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There would be many things, which is cause of not rendering theme in frontend. First check the permission of files "pub/static/frontend" folder, it should be folder 755 & files 644.
After, that check theme is applying correct or not from category.

Finally try below commands from SSH terminal in Magento root directory.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrad
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
chmod -R 777 var/ pub/static/frontend
```

Magento 2.4.2 have many things changed e.g. in cms page xml layout box removed so may it happen. you can contact me on puneetk00@gmail.com. I will fix this issue.

[Please subscribe my Youtube channel] https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChb7DM9SspzrUVh4hnWL50A